# minimum chrome version requirement for chrome app launcher

Tags: windows, google-chrome, launcher

I would like to install the chrome app launcher on my windows machine. What is the minimum version of chrome required to install the chrome app launcher?

Answer (score 0):

In General the chrome was designed to **Auto Update** itself to current version, So you could install the chrome application launcher without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install it as a separate program. Instead it gets installed automatically with a new version of chrome. Mine got installed without notification when I got chrome 29 (or was it 28? Confused between the two).